# How to turn all throws into abort conditions for debugging purposes?

Tags: c++, exception, gdb, g++, abort

In a non-trivial program, there may be any number of exceptions, being thrown and caught. While this is intended to prevent crashes, it makes debugging harder (I debug with `gdb`) since I don't get to see the point (and its backtrace) where the exception was thrown when debugging the binary unless I identify the line and introduce a break point.

So, to facilitate analysis, it would be useful to tell `g++` (or `gdb`?) to consider all `throw`s as critical errors, similar to assertion failures. Is this at all possible without hacking the code?

Comment: Your debugger should have a way to break on exceptions. I do not know `gdb` though, so I can't help with finding out how.

Comment: @DavidBrown: You are correct. I should have included gdb in my preliminary search :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's trivial. The command is `catch throw`. Start `gdb` pointing it at your executable. Issue the `catch throw` command and then the `run` command.

Comment: Ah, silly me. In my defence, I haven't been using exceptions in the past, but I'm starting to warm up to them.